# AutoHotKey: iniwrite then read of formattime not the same as result of formattime

Tags: autohotkey, ini

Here's my code:

```
IniRead, intLastMyDate, c:\temp\test.ini, section1, intLastMyDate, 130101

formattime, intCurrentMyDate, A_Now, yyMMdd

; if the ini has a date stored that is less than today, I will want to 
;    include code that restarts some other variables for a new day
; but if the date is the same as today, I want to leave those values alone,
;    no matter how many times I reload the script after fiddling with the code
if intLastMyDate < intCurrentMyDate
   {
   IniWrite, %intCurrentMyDate%, c:\temp\test.ini, section1, intLastMyDate
      ; following just to show failure of test to do what I expect
   MsgBox, if condition evals %intLastMyDate% < %intCurrentMyDate% as true
   }
```

The first time I load the script, it results as expected. When I reload it, it seems to be thinking that 130510 (the day I posted this) is less than 130510. Is this a data type problem? The help says that anything that looks like a number evals as a number ...

Answer (score 0):

Change one line:

```
if (intLastMyDate < intCurrentMyDate)
```